# Loose coupling between models in a Microservice Architecture

Tags: database-design, microservices

Under a Microservice Architecture, I am implementing 2 different micro apps: one for users administration and another for tasks administration.

**User Microservice:**

Under this micro-app I am defining a `User` model which holds all the information of the user object in the database.

**Task Microservice:**

Under this micro-app I am defining a `Task` model which holds all the information of the task object in the database, plus the user reference in the task.

Since the application is developed under a Microservice Architecture, the `User`, and `Task` models will reside in two different micro-services, and given that any task contains a user reference, I am obliged to define the user model in the Task microservice too, and this is contradicting the loose coupling concept and is a bad approach for the maintainability of the application as a whole.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are working you split your application down into services based on certain guidelines( be it biz driven or logic entities being together) and this will lead to similar problem as you have mentioned.
My take on that is when you working on your service you want to take control of what your view of that service is. User service is free to define task as they seem fit and you may use User as is or you can change user model as suited for Task service. Important thing is you get to decide (ofcourse aligned to the User service). They are source of truth for user and you are for Task.

Your view of User is built from what ever User service says but you can structure it way you want to.
So you do have to define User model but it not tightly coupled. Important thing for you is to make sure that you never share your model of user out to the world. Always the reference.

User service is free to add anything to the user model ( and remove provided others are not using and if they are, User service is breaking a contract)
And you are free to pick and choose from the User Response you get from user service.

Thats how two are decoupled.
If you talk about code redundancy, where in different services have to create a user model and make api calls and handle failures, well thats a different issue, and you can mitigate it by asking services to expose packages with models and basics calls.